# Repeating a sidebar item in wordpress depending on height of main content?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, sidebar

I have items to display in my wordpress sidebar. Let's say div1, div2, div3.

My client would like to repeat the sequence of items in the sidebar to fill the height of the sidebar to match the height of the main content area.  So, if each div is 200px height and the content in the main div on given page is 1000px, then there should be div1, div2, div3, div1, div2.

I know how to code php and write the loop, but how to know how many loops to run?

Although I think it's a bit silly, my client is adamant about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up doing this with jQuery. It's not a floating sidebar, it actually adds img tags as needed to whatever is there already, until no more fit.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var contentHeight = $('#content').height();
    var adList = [
        '<img class="ad" src="----url to first ad -----" />', 
        '<img class="ad" src="----url to second ad -----" />', 
        '<img class="ad" src="----url to third ad -----" />', 
        '<img class="ad" src="----url to fourth ad -----" />', 
        '<img class="ad" src="----url to fifth ad -----" />'
        ];
    var adHeight = 285;
    var numRequiredAds = adList.length;
    var heightDiff = contentHeight - (numRequiredAds * adHeight);
    var numAds = Math.floor(heightDiff/adHeight);
    if (heightDiff > adHeight){
        for (var i = 0; i < numAds ; i++) {
            $('#primary').append(adList[i % adList.length]);
        };
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

One solutions that come to my mind is, to use JavaScript(or JQuery) to get the height of the main content and decide how many DIVs you can add in the side bare.

EDIT: It is not efficient way to do, but assume in the loop that all the side bar contents will be displayed. then, decide in the javascript how many of the divs are to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

This type of effect is called as a "floating sidebar".We will have number of wordpress plugins available.

Simple Google search will find solution your problem.

One of the google search result is :

http://www.strx.it/2010/11/wordpress-floating-sidebar-plugin/

Comment: I know how to use Google, this is not what I was asking bout though. I don't need the sidebar to FOLLOW the user, I wanted to FILL the sidebar as much as needed. Please re-read the question.